# Сворачивать элементы в спойлер, когда они выходят за ширину экрана на всех разрешениях

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scss

Есть блок с элементами, условно с тегами, количество этих элементов может постоянно реактивно меняться, так как эти теги появляются если пользователь выбрал фильтры.
Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы как только добавленный элемент стал не помещаться в ширину окна текущего разрешения, он прятался в спойлер и появлялась кнопка "ещё". Все элементы до этой кнопки остаются на своих местах, а новые прячутся в спойлер, если не помещаются.
Ширина экрана соответственно может быть любой, у элементов также нет жесткой ширины, но они не могут быть больше 220px.

Очень жду любые идеи как такое реализовать и в каком направлении двигаться

Comment: Ну если vue  или  react,  можно условным рендором сделать. Например проверив, что если блок вышел за придел, отрендрить одну часть иначе другую.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил вам использовать `IntersectionObserver` для реализации проверки, собственно, нахождения элемента в нужной вам области, а для показа разного контента использовать условную отрисовку (`v-if` etc.) отталкиваясь от `IntersectionObserver`.